# vuetify crashes with ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications

Tags: vue.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm running vue v3.3.8 and vuetify v3.3.23 as part of upgrading from vue2/vuetify2.

Whenever a v-select or v-autocomplete in the new version contains items with "longer texts" then, when clicking the component to expand the select-list, it crashes with "ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications".

To reproduce, make sure an item has a long text and click to expand the select-list. It can also be reproduced by making the browser window really narrow (then the crash can be reproduced with even relatively short texts in the select items).

I saw that there was a never version of vuetify than the one I'm using but upgrading to that one caused a lot of other, weird, errors.

Anyways, is there anyone who knows if there is a permanent fix for this problem?

UPDATE
I sort of "solved" it by adding this code to my vue.config.js:

```
devServer: {
// --- This hides the "ResizeObserver loop-error" ------
client: {
  overlay: {
    runtimeErrors: (error) => {
      const ignoreErrors = [
        "ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded",
        "ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications.",
      ];
      if (ignoreErrors.includes(error.message)) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
},
},
```

I found someone else experiencing the same error and this "fix" hides the error which makes it as if it never occurs in the first place. I cant see any sideeffects on the page either so this fix works fine for me.